# Datagrid Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to display Data in datagrid in wpf.What is the way to show data dynamically.

```
Random rm = new Random();
Random rm2 = new Random();
string code = "034" + rm2.Next(0, 7);
string num = code + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9);

for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    code = "034" + rm2.Next(0, 7);
    num = code + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) ;
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = num.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rm = new Random();
    Random rm2 = new Random();
    string code = "034" + rm2.Next(0, 7);
    List<string> numList = new List<string>();
    string num = code + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9);



    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
    {

        code = "034" + rm2.Next(0, 7);
        num = code + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) ;

       numList.Add(num);
    }
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = numList;
```

Update your code with this. It should work.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set any type which implements `IEnumerable` as `ItemsSource` for `DataGrid`.

For example, `ObservableCollection<T>`:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"></DataGrid>
```

code-behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
   FillDataGrid();

}

private void FillDataGrid()
{
   ObservableCollection<Person> coll = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
   for (int start = 0; start < 10; start++)
   {
       coll.Add(new Person() { IdPerson = start, Name = "Bill" + start.ToString(), SurName = "ONeill" });
   }
   dataGrid.ItemsSource = coll;
}
```

Model class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int IdPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

**OR using DataTable:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
   FillDataGrid();
}

private DataTable employeeDataTable;
private void FillDataGrid()
{
    employeeDataTable = new DataTable();
    employeeDataTable = _ds.Tables.Add("DT");
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
       employeeDataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       var theRow = employeeDataTable.NewRow();
       for (int j = 0; j < 80; j++)
       {
          theRow[j] = "a";
       }
       employeeDataTable.Rows.Add(theRow);
    }
    gridEmployees.ItemsSource = employeeDataTable.DefaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can assign all the `num` values to a List or an Observable Collection. Then you can set this List or Collection as itemsource for your datagrid.

```
List<string> numLst = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    code = "034" + rm2.Next(0, 7);
    num = code + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) + rm.Next(0, 9) ;
    numLst.Add(num);
}
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = numLst;
```